# Convert UTC epoch to local timestamp, for SQL query

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following information in my SQL table:

SELECT * FROM `table`

```
id          epic                    bid     offer   update_time
136449187   CS.D.EURGBP.TODAY.IP    7010.9  7011.9  1447854279749
136449186   CC.D.LCO.USS.IP         4430.1  4433.1  1447854279696
136449185   CS.D.USDJPY.TODAY.IP    12344.1 12344.9 1447854279679
136449184   CC.D.RB.USS.IP          12507   12527   1447854279636
136449179   IX.D.DAX.DAILY.IP       10955   10956   1447854279597
136449183   CS.D.COPPER.TODAY.IP    4610.8  4620.8  1447854279593
136449182   CC.D.HO.USS.IP          13969   13989   1447854279561
136449181   CS.D.EURCHF.TODAY.IP    10837.7 10839.7 1447854279559
```

where update_time is a UTC epoch (integer)

how would I be able to extract only the rows that fall between 2015-11-18 08:00:00 (Europe) and 2015-11-18 21:30:00 (Europe)

Im not sure how to convert a local timestamp into the UTC equivalent in MYSQL so that I can extract the relevant rows.

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME(), TO_UNIXTIME()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive managed to figure out a solution!

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE update_time > unix_timestamp( convert_TZ( '2015-11-19 08:00:00', '+01:00', '+00:00' ) ) *1000
```

convert_TZ( '2015-11-19 08:00:00', '+01:00', '+00:00' )
 - This converts a given time in string format to UTC timestamp.  I have to use timing offsets as I currently don't have timezone tables installed in my SQL.

Unix_timestampp() then converts UTC timestamp into an epoch.  As this is in seconds and I want to compare to the field update_time in my table which is in milliseconds, I then multiplied the result by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select from_unixtime(substr(update_time,1,length(update_time)-3)) from table;
```

last 3 digits are milliseconds which u cannot possibly display

```
+------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| up_time    | from_unixtime(up_time) | date                |
+------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| 1435870857 | 2015-07-02 17:00:57    | 2015-07-02 17:00:57 |
|  899413267 | 1998-07-02 17:01:07    | 1998-07-02 17:01:07 |
| 1435870867 | 2015-07-02 17:01:07    | 2015-07-02 17:01:07 |
| 1436760000 | 2015-07-13 00:00:00    | 2015-07-13 00:00:00 |
| 1436760000 | 2015-07-13 00:00:00    | 2015-07-13 00:00:00 |
| 1436984796 | 2015-07-15 14:26:36    | 2015-07-15 14:26:36 |
| 1436984977 | 2015-07-15 14:29:37    | 2015-07-15 14:29:37 |
| 1436984993 | 2015-07-15 14:29:53    | 2015-07-15 14:29:53 |
| 1436587200 | 2015-07-11 00:00:00    | 2015-07-11 00:00:00 |
| 1437451200 | 2015-07-21 00:00:00    | 2015-07-21 00:00:00 |
| 1437443325 | 2015-07-20 21:48:45    | 2015-07-20 21:48:45 |
| 1437471045 | 2015-07-21 05:30:45    | 2015-07-21 05:30:45 |
| 1437442185 | 2015-07-20 21:29:45    | 2015-07-20 21:29:45 |
| 1437470985 | 2015-07-21 05:29:45    | 2015-07-21 05:29:45 |
| 1437463845 | 2015-07-21 03:30:45    | 2015-07-21 03:30:45 |
| 1447696656 | 2015-11-16 12:57:36    | 2015-11-16 12:57:36 |
| 1447696628 | 2015-11-16 12:57:08    | 2015-11-16 12:57:08 |
+------------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: This is a better solution, you can simply divide by 1000

    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( `update_time` /1000, "%Y-%m-%d" ) FROM table


But it still doesnt answer how I can convert a time given in "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS" format for any given timezone (in this case Europe), into UTC equivalent, and then subsequently into a epoch so that a comparison can be made